# Make parent object not appearing within session.dirty of before_flush event listener

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have been playing around with SQLAlchemy and found out that I cannot track reliably what is being changed within database.

I have created an example that explains what my concern is:

```
import re
import datetime

from sqlalchemy import create_engine

from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import (
    declarative_base,
    declared_attr,
    )

from sqlalchemy import (
    create_engine,
    event,
    Column,
    Boolean,
    Integer,
    String,
    Unicode,
    DateTime,
    Index,
    ForeignKey,
    CheckConstraint,
    )

from sqlalchemy.orm import (
    scoped_session,
    sessionmaker,
    Session,
    relationship,
    backref,
    )

import transaction

from zope.sqlalchemy import ZopeTransactionExtension

class ExtendedSession(Session):
    my_var = None

DBSession = scoped_session(
    sessionmaker(extension=ZopeTransactionExtension(),
        class_=ExtendedSession
        )
    )

class BaseModel(object):
    query = DBSession.query_property()

    id = Column(
        Integer,
        primary_key=True,
        )

    @declared_attr
    def __tablename__(cls):
        class_name = re.sub(r"([A-Z])", r"_\1", cls.__name__).lower()[1:]
        return "{0}".format(
            class_name,
            )

Base = declarative_base(cls=BaseModel)

def initialize_sql(engine):
    DBSession.configure(bind=engine)
    Base.metadata.bind = engine

engine = create_engine("sqlite://")
initialize_sql(engine)

class Parent(Base):
    # *** Columns
    col1 = Column (
        String,
        nullable=False,
        )
    # *** Relationships
    # *** Methods
    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Parent(id: '{0}', col1: '{1}')>".format(
            self.id,\
            self.col1,\
            )

class Child(Base):
    # *** Columns
    col1 = Column (
        String,
        nullable=False,
        )
    parent_id = Column (
        Integer,
        ForeignKey (
            Parent.id,
            ondelete="CASCADE",
            ),
        nullable=False,
        )
    # *** Relationships
    parent = relationship (
        Parent,
        backref=backref(
            "child_elements",
            uselist=True,
            cascade="save-update, delete",
            lazy="dynamic",
            ),
        # If below is uncommented then instance of Parent won't appear in session.dirty
        # However this relationship will never be loaded (even if needed)
        #lazy="noload",
        )
    # *** Methods
    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Child(id: '{0}', col1: '{1}', parent_id: '{2}')>".format(
            self.id,\
            self.col1,\
            self.parent_id,\
            )

@event.listens_for(DBSession, 'before_flush')
def before_flush(session, flush_context, instances):
    time_stamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

    if session.new:
        for elem in session.new:
            print(" ### NEW {0}".format(repr(elem)))

    if session.dirty:
        for elem in session.dirty:
            print(" ### DIRTY {0}".format(repr(elem)))

    if session.deleted:
        for elem in session.deleted:
            print(" ### DELETED {0}".format(repr(elem)))

Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

with transaction.manager:
    parent = Parent(col1="parent")
    DBSession.add(parent)
    DBSession.flush()

    # Below loop is to demonstrate that
    # each time child object is created and linked to parent
    # parent is also marked as modified
    # how to avoid that?
    # or optionally is it possible to detect this in before_flush event
    # without issuing additional SQL query?
    for i in range(0, 10):
        parent=Parent.query.filter(Parent.col1 == "parent").first()
        child = Child(col1="{0}".format(i))
        child.parent = parent
        DBSession.add(child)
        DBSession.flush()

    # Below update will not cause associated instance of Parent appearing in session.dirty
    child = Child.query.filter(Child.col1=="3").first()
    child.col1="updated"
    DBSession.add(child)
    DBSession.flush()
```

In short - there are two objects:

- Parent
- Child - linked to Parent

Each time I add new instance of Child and link it with instance of Parent that instance of Parent also appears within session.dirty of before_flush event.

SQLAlchemy community adviced this behavior is expected (although I think there must be an option to change default behavior - I could not find it within doco)

So here is my question: is it possible to configure relationship such way that when I add a new instance of Child and link it to instance of Parent then that instance of Parent won't appear within session.dirty?

I have tried setting relationship as `lazy="noload"` and it is not an option since I may need to use that relationship (so I may need to load it)

I would also accept a solution that would allow me to detect that Parent have not been changed within before_load event handler - however I do not want to trigger additional query to achieve this.

I would appreciate your help,

Greg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After hours of research and a hint from SQLAlchemy community I found solution that seems to work the way I need (notice additional condition within `session.dirty` block).

```
@event.listens_for(DBSession, 'before_flush')
def before_flush(session, flush_context, instances):
    time_stamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

    if session.new:
        for elem in session.new:
            print(" ### NEW {0}".format(repr(elem)))

    if session.dirty:
        for elem in session.dirty:
            # Below check was added to solve the problem
            if ( session.is_modified(elem, include_collections=False) ):
                print(" ### DIRTY {0}".format(repr(elem)))

    if session.deleted:
        for elem in session.deleted:
            print(" ### DELETED {0}".format(repr(elem)))
```

The documentation related to my solution can be found here: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.is_modified

In short - specifying `include_collections=False` within `session.is_modified` makes SQLAlchemy to ignore situations where multivalued collections have been changed (in my case if child was changed then parent would be filtered out by that additional check).